# On orientation change button touchlistener not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

I have two layouts table.xml(port) and table.xml(land) which from there names one of the landscape and other for the protrait.

[image]

I have included this layout in another layout called fragment_test.xml like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

   <include layout="@layout/table"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my fragment code of the above layout fragment_test:

```
public class Fragment_test extends Fragment  implements View.OnTouchListener{
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



         mytable= (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mytableid);
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),   "fonts/font.ttf");

                  for (int i = 0; i < table1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    LinearLayout mychild = (LinearLayout) mytable.getChildAt(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < mychild.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        Button b = (Button) child.getChildAt(j);
                        b.setTypeface(typeface);
                         b.setOnTouchListener(this);
                   }

                }
            }

         }


        //this is called when a button is touched
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return true;
    }

}
```

So basically I have several buttons in the table layout I am looping through to setontouchlistener for each one of them.

So my problem is when I switch from protrait to landscape or the opposite the touchlistener of the button does not work anymore and even the typeface doesn't work anymore when changing the layout.

**> Edit:** this is the activity code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");


       FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
       manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new Fragment_test(), "mytag").commit();

    }
```

Comment: Post activity code

Comment: i added the activity code but i dont think thats related since i debugged the code and the fragment onActivityCreated  is getting called normally whenever  i changed the orientation

Comment: Where is `table1` coming from, and what is the child count size on each rotation ?

Comment: i dont think the problem is related to the table since if i launch the in protrait  or landscape mode it works fine but if i switch from protrait to landscape or the opposite it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `setRetainInstance(true)` after `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);`

[here is the documentation of setRetainInstance(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))

Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment myFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("myFragment");
    if (myFragment == null) {
        myFragment = new ParentFragment();
    }

    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentHolder, myFragment, "myFragment").commit();
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
}
```

Comment: please post your @layout/table.

Comment: @has19 `setRetainInstance(true)`  fails as you are adding a new fragment instance every time onCreate is called (every rotation).  In the Hosting Activity find the fragment via its tag, if null, create a new instance then begin the transaction using the new fragment, or current fragment instance.

Comment: you should include what @Mark Keen said to accept your answer else it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I am just give you the information.

you can check the `Orientataion` of device this way and set it layout.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setContentView(R.layout.table_horizontal);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }else if (newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setContentView(R.layout.table_vertical);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: but this code works only for activities not fragment